# Overriding internal UIViewController methods because an internal method is giving me bugs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

What are the consequences of overriding internal UIViewController methods?

`[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]` is giving me some problems. It resizes my frame to values I do not desire ***sometimes***. I do not even know where it picks off the new frame's values (it is close to the size of the superview to where I am adding it, but is off by 2px). Reference: [this question, which I also need some help with.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701736/addsubview-modifying-the-added-views-frame)

I tried defining an empty `- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)window shouldAppearOrDisappear:(BOOL)flag` method in my view controller. Bug is gone. >.<

Does anyone know if overriding `-viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:` is ok to do? Or some other workaround?

Or, does anyone know when and why `-viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:` likes to change my frame dimensions ***sometimes***?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Do have you finally submitted a bug?

Answer (score 2):

If you override that method you run the risk of getting rejected, it is undocumented. An approach that isn't against the rules is to override the `setFrame:` method of the view in the view controller though.

If you believe this is a bug, put together a minimal test case and submit it to http://bugreport.apple.com and potentially upload it somewhere that we can see exactly what is happening as well.

Comment: App rejection is my main concern. I will try the setFrame override approach.

Comment: I'm still interested to know why viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear: will sometimes try to resize my frame though.

Comment: I would definitely submit a bug report. I'm not sure why that would be happening.

Answer (score 2):

For the "why" part of your question; the frame can automatically change in two situations:

1. Your ViewController is part of a view controller hierarchy (Navigation or TabBar). In this case your parent ViewControllers do as they please with your views frame.
2. Your view allows autosizing and the parent view changes size. The thing to note here is that the size of the root view is changed to fit the screen, causing autosizing to happen for all subviews.

To find the exact culprit in your case you could set a breakpoint in the overridden `setFrame:`.

Comment: The view in question is not the one directly added to a view controller heirarchy, but a subview of a subview of one. No parent views change size either. Anyway, I'm not sure if this problem still exists, this was encountered in iOS 3.2.

Comment: @altealice I was just trying to find the exact culrit in your case as i experienced weirdness myself (comming fron UINavigationController). I don't know if this is fixed or not in the last iOS, but, from my experience with UINavigationController, you can expect weird frame chnages if your view has a view controller (regardless of depth of embeding in other views).

Comment: I see. Thanks for sharing your findings. Maybe someday we can find out that it is really fixed, or at least find the exact case when this happens. :)